How to add date filter to graph?
I am writing an app that allows the user to select a date range, and the graph will change accordingly. However, I am having issues with my filter() function. If I hardcode the dates i.e. y >= '6/11/2024' & y <= '6/13/2024', the app runs fine. However, when I attempt to make the filter reactive with input$data_range, the graph shows up blank. I tried wrapping my data frame column and the input in as.Date, but my graph still shows up as blank.
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

ui <- fluidPage(
  dateRangeInput('date_range', 'Pick Range',
                 start = '2024-06-11',
                 end = '2024-06-13',
                 min = '2024-06-11',
                 max = '2024-06-15'),
  actionButton('run', 'Run'),
  plotOutput('plot')
)

server <- function(input,output){

data_input <- structure(list(length = 0:4, sec = c("00:00.0", "00:01.0", "00:02.0", "00:03.0", "00:04.0"), time = c(30L, 40L, 50L, 60L, 70L), colors = c(5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L), y = c("6/11/2024", "6/12/2024", "6/13/2024", "6/14/2024", "6/15/2024")), row.names = c(NA, 5L), class = "data.frame")

data_filtered <- eventReactive(input$run,
  filter(data_input, as.Date(y) >= as.Date(input$date_range[1]) & as.Date(y) <= as.Date(input$date_range[2]))
)

output$plot <- renderPlot(
ggplot(data_filtered(), aes(x = y, y = time))+geom_point()
)
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)


The issue is that the y column of date_input isn't a proper date in the standard format. Convert this column to a date using e.g. date_input  <- date_input |> mutate(y = lubridate::mdy(y)) and your app works fine.

@stefan thank you, that worked! Not sure if this would belong in a new question, but if I wanted the min and max in dateRangeInput to be dependent on the min and max dates of my dataset, would I need updatedateRangeInput?

Yup. In this case updatedateRangeInput is the way to go.

I fixed your code and it works now:
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)


ui <- fluidPage(
  dateRangeInput('date_range', 'Pick Range',
                 start = '2024-06-11',
                 end = '2024-06-13',
                 min = '2024-06-11',
                 max = '2024-06-15'),
  actionButton('run', 'Run'),
  plotOutput('plot')
)

server <- function(input,output){
  
  data_input <- structure(list(length = 0:4, sec = c("00:00.0", "00:01.0", "00:02.0", "00:03.0", "00:04.0"), time = c(30L, 40L, 50L, 60L, 70L), colors = c(5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L), y = c("2024-6-11", "2024-6-12", "2024-6-13", "2024-6-14", "2024-6-15")), row.names = c(NA, 5L), class = "data.frame")
  
  data_filtered <- eventReactive(input$run,
                                 filter(data_input, lubridate::ymd(y) >= input$date_range[1] & lubridate::ymd(y) <= input$date_range[2])
  )
  
  output$plot <- renderPlot(
    ggplot(data_filtered(), aes(x = y, y = time))+geom_point()
  )
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)

The date format of the Y column was wrong, which made it impossible for your data to be filtered. I reformatted it to be compatible with the yyyy-mm-dd format of dateRangeInput() using lubridate's ymd() function.

Thank you for your solution, it works perfect! If the Y column instead looks like mm-dd-yyyy hh-mm-ss, would you recommend splitting into two columns by date and time? Or another method?

I am glad the solution works. If the Y column is in the mm-dd-yyyy hh-mm-ss format, you should use the mdy_hms() function from the lubridate package to parse it into a datetime object. Please take a look at the lubridate documentation for better guidance https://lubridate.tidyverse.org/

For some reason, when I input the same data as a .csv, I get an error saying all formats failed to parse, no formats found. Any idea why this is happening, since the data is the exact same? data_input <- read.csv('Testy.csv') instead of data_input <- structure(list(length = 0:4, sec = c("00:00.0", "00:01.0", "00:02.0", "00:03.0", "00:04.0"), time = c(30L, 40L, 50L, 60L, 70L), colors = c(5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L), y = c("2024-6-11", "2024-6-12", "2024-6-13", "2024-6-14", "2024-6-15")), row.names = c(NA, 5L), class = "data.frame")

After reading the data as a CSV, try converting it to either a data frame or a tibble with as.data.frame() or tidyverse::tibble() and see if it works.
